# Unicorn optimize with unicorn killer gives worst performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I used 'unicorn-worker-killer' gem with the some additional modificationfrom here for ruby GC http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/05/28/unicorn-rawk-kick-gc-out-of-the-band/

But after the following instruction both there(https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer) and deployed to production server. My application performance degrade gradually like

1. App server response time goes from 350 ms avg to 1100 ms
2. Page loading time goes from 6s avg to 13s

Also my heroku combination is:

1. 6 Web dyno with 1 gb memory
2. 1 woker dyno with 1x speed.
3. unicron worker process is 3
4. my db connection is 40 and set db pool 2 at heroku.

Please help me about how i optimize page loading time and app server time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to diagnose your issue.

I would recommend you don't use this unicorn worker killer gem.  You're better off using a normal application server like unicorn configured for Heroku unless you have a specific problem (hung workers or memory leaks).

If you want to diagnose your performance problems and load times, the best thing to do is use a service like NewRelic (available as a Heroku add-on) that will allow you to measure your request times and drill down into what specifically is a bottle neck and then fix that.

Comment: The unicorn-worker-killer gem doesn't replace unicorn, it's intended to complement it by killing unicorn processes after they've served a given number of requests or exceeded some memory limit. It might be helpful, but only if the slow load times are because of a slow memory leak. I agree that the actual bottleneck needs to be identified first.